# was hoping to have done

Tags: grammar, sentence-meaning

Can someone please tell us about the grammar and the meaning of this structure? I've come across it in a book.

> Adrian was hoping to have raised enough money to buy a new computer for the school.

was hoping + to have + past participle sounds weird and unfamiliar. Is this a wish or a hope at all?

Comment: "to be + hoping" does not appear in this sentence. _"Was hoping"_ is the _past progressive_ tense of the verb _"hope"_. Have you studied the past tense in English?

Comment: @P.E.Dant my main question is about "to have raised". You can be less sarcastic by the way.

Comment: No sarcasm was intended. Not every participant here knows that the past progressive is formed by using the linking verb, and your question (before it was edited) indicated that you were unaware of this. If we do not ask the question, how will we know the answer? _Hope_ takes the infinitive, and in your case it takes the _perfect infinitive_ of _raise_, which is _"to have raised"_. Many verbs in English take the infinitive, e.g. _care_, _manage_, _fail_, _learn_, _strive_, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Hoping to have raised" is indeed a hope, although it's a hope for an implied event: he is hoping TO FIND OUT that he had raised enough money.

Answer (score 0):

This structure is called "perfect infinitive" and is often used to express one's hopes, desires or claims, both those that might have happened in the past and those that one wishes will happen in the future. But what do I know? You'd better look in the Cambridge dictionary [here](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/perfect-infinitive-with-to-to-have-worked) or just search "perfect infinitive" in a search engine of your choice.